# Emulator not running the application

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-emulator

I am trying to setup flutter on my device, so far I have been able to download the flutter SDK and android studio and satisfy the conditions of `flutter doctor` to start learning android application development:-
[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v29Ra.png)

I ignored the absence of visual studio as I don't want my app to be compatible with windows(as I am trying to develop for Android) but I am not able to fix the missing java bundle, any help on how would I do that?

I just ignored it for a second and moved on to set up my emulator but on running, it shows a pop up which says "Attach a debugger or ESC to cancel"(the pop-up is something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPow6.png)) how would I fix it.
This doesn't run the app on the emulator so how would I fix that?

Also on trying to debug, it throws [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YxuB.png), I am totally confused on how to proceed further to at least run my app so that I could start developing and learning flutter?
I am following along [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#2) to run my application.

**Edit:**

I have the java bundle in place but don't know how would I configure Android Studio to get it.

[java's prescence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZTOi.png)

Also that the emulator is now showing that the **System UI is not responding** and on closing it, it further shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDqzb.png).

It's been a week since I am trying to work out the setup of flutter but some way or the other some issue happens, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install java runtime environment and It'll work. [get from here](https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)

Comment: I have java jdk(with verison 19) in place with JAVA_HOME variable setup. It has jre included in it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: click here]
it'll show like this if you have JDK installed properly.

Comment: I have made some edits, can you please elaborate on how would I configure Android Studio to get the bundle?

Comment: which android studio version are you using?  and which operating system?